# How to take a dot product of 2D sparse tensor and 3D dense matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tensor, dot-product

A tensor dot product of 2D dense tensor and 3D dense tensor can be done as follows:

```
shape=[2,4,3]
dense2d  = tf.constant([[0,1.0,2.0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
dense3d  = tf.placeholder("float", shape=shape)
res = tf.tensordot(dense3d,dense2d,axes=1)
res.set_shape(shape)
```

Can we produce the same result using instead a 2D sparse tensor? What would the code be if we had

```
sparse2d = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1.0, 2.0], dense_shape=[3,3])
```

instead of `dense2d`?

FYI, this post is related to this github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9210). I understand that `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul` doesn't support rank > 2. Is there a workaround?